# "Не" слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

*Отсутствие штампа не всегда означает, что бланк не действителен. Представителям малого бизнеса, например, ее иметь не обязательно.*

Comment: Штамп, бланк — слова муж. рода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Отсутствие штампа не всегда означает, что бланк недействителен. Представителям малого бизнеса, например, его иметь не обязательно.*

В первом случае естественнее утверждать недействительность бланка, чем отрицать действительность. Бланк каков? Недействителен. Во втором же случае логичнее отрицание по глаголу "иметь". Можно заменить на *её иметь не нужно.* Мы же не напишем "ненужно". Такое слово существует в значении "бесполезно", но это не наш случай.

Как правильно заметили shampar и grizzly, "штамп" мужского рода, поэтому конечно же "её" заменяем на "его"!

Comment: "Можно заменить на *её иметь не нужно*" — я тоже никак не пойму, о какой **её** идёт речь.

Comment: @grizzly: почему тоже? Речь о конце последнего предложения.

Comment: То есть о штампе? Тогда *его*, а не *её*. А если речь о печати, тогда допущена какая-то стилистическая ошибка, я думаю.

Comment: Всё, дошло! Вы, как и shampar. А я просто его комментария не понял и не заметил нестыковки смысловой. Спасибо!